# Find lists items closest to certain values in Python

Tags: python, nearest-neighbor, bins

I have a list of sorted floats `y`, as well as a list of unsorted floats `x`.

Now, I need to find out for every element in `x` between which values of `y` it lies, preferably by index of `y`. So for example, if

```
y=[1,2,3,4,5]

x[0]=3.5
```

I would need the output for index `0` of `x` to be `(2,3)`, because `3.5` is between `y[2]` and `y[3]`.

Basically, it is the same as seeing `y` as bin edges and sorting `x` to those bins, I guess.

What would be the easiest way yo accomplish that?

Comment: Try writing some code first. You might surprise yourself and find the easiest way.

Comment: Have you tried actually sorting x?

Answer (score 6):

I would use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) ([`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) in Python 2.x) to accomplish this:

```
from itertools import islice#, izip as zip # if Python 2.x

def nearest_neighbours(x, lst):
    for l1, l2 in zip(lst, islice(lst, 1, None)):
        if l1 <= x <= l2:
            return l1, l2
    else:
        # ?
```

Example usage:

```
>>> nearest_neighbours(3.5, range(1, 6))
(3, 4)
```

You will have to decide what you want to happen if `x` isn't between any pair in `lst` (i.e. replace `# ?`!) If you want indices (although your example isn't using them), have a play with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks - I'm aware of how to code that step-by-step. However, I was looking for a pretty/easy/elegant solution and now I am using numpy.digitize(), wich looks pretty to me and works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Q: What would be the easiest way yo accomplish that?

Instead of giving you the code, I think you should see this pseudo-code and **try to write your own code! Don't just copy paste code from the internet, if you want to educate yourself!**

Pseudocode:

```
// Assume that when you have a tie,
// you put the number in the smallest range
// Here, b is between 2.1 and 3.5, instead of
// 3.5 and 4.1
float a[5] = {0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.5, 4.1}; // your y
float b = 3.5;                          // your x

// counter for the loop and indexes. Init i to second element
integer i = 1, prev = -1, next;

// while we are not in the end of the array
while(i < 5) {
    // if b is in the range of ( a(i-1), a(i) ]
    if(b <= a[i] && b > a[i - 1]) {
    // mark the indexes
        prev = i - 1;
        next = i;
    }

    // go to next element
    i++;
}

if(prev = -1)
    print "Number is not between some numbers"
else
    print "prev, next"
```

I think that this can make you understand the point and then be able to select the easiest way for you.